# Point domain name to google compute engine

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine, nameservers, a-records

I have recently setup a google compute engine and configured to host my website . so, to make the website accessible by domain name I used a one that I've got it from just host but i still get at the most of time the blue screen of justhost .
remark: on justhost i can just change the name server so that's why I passed via Cloudns to change DNS records and point to my compute engine IP

Answer (score 27):

You can create A record with your domain host and point it to the Public IP of your GCE instance. Don't forget to [reserve a static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#reserve_new_static) for your GCE instance instead of a ephemeral IP, in order to make sure your IP doesn't change.

Comment: Looks like you never got marked as answered correctly but I wanted to upvote your solution as it was helpful to me. Also for dealing with the IPs this documentation may be useful for others:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses