# Setting up fully qualified domain name in Google Compute Instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, fqdn

Many infrastructure configurations require a fully qualified domain name to set up. 
 How do we set an FQDN on google compute instances?
FQDN that can be used internally within the VPC and / or FQDN that can be used externally

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041837/point-domain-name-to-google-compute-engine

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documents that explain how the [FQDN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#instance_fully_qualified_domain_names) works in an instance of compute engine.

Maybe this solution fit your needs:

```
# edit the hosts file and add your FQDN
$ sudo vi /etc/hosts  
# prevent the overwrite 
$ sudo +i chattr -i /etc/hosts
```

Also you can use Google Cloud DNS and use it as internal DNS by editing the  resolv.conf file